# In Leviticus 23:20 did they wave the bread of firstfruits along with the lambs?

Tags: word-study, leviticus

Leviticus 23:20 (KJV, emphasis added):

> And the priest shall ***wave*** them with the bread of the firstfruits for a wave offering before the LORD with the two lambs:  they shall be holy to the LORD for the priest.

If the lambs were waved:

1. How were they waved?
2. Were they alive when they were waved?

Comment: See Jewish Encyclopedia: "[Sacrifice / Waving and Heaving](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14796-wave-offering#anchor12)" : "This ceremony ... not further described ..."

Answer (score 1):

[SACRIFICE - JewishEncyclopedia.com](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14796-wave-offering#anchor12):

> **Terumah**: … Where terumah or heaving was prescribed, the part subject to this rite was moved perpendicularly down and up, or up and down. In tenufah or waving the motion was horizontal from left to right or vice versa

> **Samaritan**: … others again served as slaughterers and sprinkled the blood of the victims on the altar; while still others were employed in waving the parts prescribed for the wave-offering.

It would appear that only specific parts of the slaughtered lambs were waved, and in a horizontal, not vertical direction.